# Trying to implement a more efficient way but code is not working (Fibonacci recursive)

Tags: java

I'm trying to use an array to store value of fibo to save time during recursive calls. Somehow I'm getting indexoutofBounds. Here is my code thus far:

```
public static long fibo(int n, ArrayList<Long> arr) {
        if (n > 20 || n < 0) {
            return -1;
        } else if (arr.size() >  n) {
            return arr.get(n);
        }

        long v;
        if (n == 0) {
            v = 0;
        } else if (n == 1) {
            v = 1;
        } else {
            v = fibo(n-1, arr) + fibo(n-2, arr);
        }
        arr.add(n, v);
        return v;
    }
```

Error Message generate

```
java -classpath .:/run_dir/junit-4.12.jar:target/dependency/* Main
0 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:788)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:513)
    at Main.fibo(Main.java:25)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
exit status 1
```

Oh btw, the restriction for n is that `0 <= n <= 20`

Comment: When asking about an exception **always** post the complete stack trace of the exception, as it helps us pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting exception as when fib() is called for n>=1, n=0 is never evaluated. As a result, the first element added is at n=1 while arrayList size is 0.

Possible solutions:

```
public class Fib {
    public static long fibo(int n, ArrayList<Long> arr) {
        if (n > 20 || n < 0) {
            return -1;
        } else if (arr.size() >  n) {
            return arr.get(n);
        }

        var v = fibo(n-1, arr) + fibo(n-2, arr);
        arr.add(n, v);
        return v;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var cache = new ArrayList<Long>();
        cache.add(0, 1L);
        cache.add(1, 1L);
        var res = fibo(19, cache);
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

However, best practice is using HashMap for cache and using cache as an instance variable which is initialized with object initialization.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Fib {
    Map<Integer, Long> cache = new HashMap<>() {{
        put(0, 1L);
        put(1, 1L);
    }};

    public long fibo(int n) {
        if (n > 20 || n < 0) {
            return -1;
        } else if (cache.containsKey(n)) {
            return cache.get(n);
        }

        var v = fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2);
        cache.put(n, v);
        return v;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var res = new Fib().fibo(19);
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the call:

```
arr.add(n, v);
```

Which tries to insert the value `v` at position `n`. If you step through your code you see that the *first* values it reaches this line with are `n = 1` and `v = 1`.

This means it tries to insert a value at index 1 into an empty list. By definition you can only insert something at index 0 into an empty list and since `fibo` gets called with `n = 1` before it gets called with `n = 0` the index 0 will not be occupied with anything yet.

If you *know* a low upper bound, then using a simple fixed-size array (`long[]`) instead of a growing `ArrayList` might be a better approach.

Comment: Oh I just realized. Will putting the array into a separate class work instead of passing the array as parameter?

Comment: That wouldn't change anything fundamentally about how you interact with it. So no, it wouldn't solve this problem. But yes, if you fix the logic, you could also move it to another place and it'd still work.